# Creating Treemaps with subcategories

Tags: r, ggplot2, treemap

I have a dataset with categorical and numerical data and I am trying to create a treemap in ggplot2 using package treemap, as the image below, but I need some alterations that I can not figure out how to do.

[image]

My numerical variable means the variation of the parameter and when the values are higher than 1, it means increase while values lower than 1 means decrease. In this plot, small values have small sizes, so I loose some information. How can I show in the code that I need values below 1 to be considered as an inverse degree of intensity?

Also, I need the variables to be distinctively separated with labels on the top.

Here is an example of my data.

| kind_of_measure | cause_variation_turb | associated_condit | kind_particle | unit | variation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| repeat_time | dam_removal |  | suspended_solids | FNU | 39.24 |
| repeat_time | dam_removal |  | suspended_solids | NTU | 3.93 |
| repeat_time | dam_flush |  | suspended_solids | FNU | 48.57 |
| repeat_time | dam_flush |  | suspended_solids | FNU | 103.8 |
| repeat_time | dam_flush |  | suspended_solids | FNU | 0.16 |
| repeat_time | dam_flush |  | suspended_solids | FNU | 78.14 |
| repeat_time | dam_flush |  | suspended_solids | FNU | 63.2 |
| repeat_time | dam_flush |  | suspended_solids | FNU | 50.92 |
| repeat_time | sediment_washout | el_nino | suspended_solids | TSS | 54 |
| dif_places | deforestation |  | suspended_solids | NTU | 0.02 |
| dif_places | deforestation |  | suspended_solids | TSS | 4.2 |
| repeat_time | mining_dam_break | copper_gold | tailing | NTU | 0.29 |
| repeat_time | drought |  | algal_biomass | NTU | 2.87 |
| repeat_time | wetland_restoration | wastewater_effluent | suspended_solids | TSS | 3.16 |
| repeat_time | fire |  | ashes | TSS | 12.92 |
| dif_places | best_management_practices | cattle_grazing | suspended_solids | TDS | 382.32 |

Any help is welcome :)